# Managed Dll Injection without C/C++ or Assembly

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll-injection, codecave

How to inject managed dll in remote process using VB/C# without using any C/C++ bootstrap dll or any code cave written in assembly.

Comment: have you tried: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/197571

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code and config you tried so far?

Comment: This wasn't a real question then...

Comment: This was not question like this, i wanted to share my knowledge, so i answered my own question

Answer (score 1):

Dll Export is required for exporting function as native code

**Classical Mechanism:**

Following is the procedure of classical dll injection:

- Create C/C++ Dll
- Write Dll Path to remote process
- Create Remote thread to LoadLibraryA along with argument as Dll Path
- Dll Entry point will be invoked at this stage

Reference: [Code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607352/Injecting-Net-Assemblies-Into-Unmanaged-Processes)

**Codecave Method:**

With this method you can skip C/C++ Dll but requires basic knowledge of Assembly

- Create code-cave at run-time as byte array and write to other process, or write assembly procedure (c like function) and compile it as binary code, which will load .net assembly
- Write your code to other process
- Create remote thread and your .net assembly can be loaded

Reference: [Code with example](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:RIQRjSJ3UjIJ:www.emoticode.net/embed/c-plus-plus/win32-dll-injection-with-writeprocessmemory-and-opcode-patching.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)
[Original Link seems to expired so google cached version]

**Modern Way:**

This method is so easy to use and doesn't require knowledge of C/C++ or Assembly, the following is procedure

- Load your library in current process and get procedure address you want to call, it will work with procedure with one argument
- Call create remote thread in target process with LoadLibrary and argument as your managed dll path. This will not execute your code instead only loads your library in target process
- Wait for thread to exit and then get return code, this is your library module handle
- Now create remote thread at your procedure address in remote process, and its done, your procedure will be called.

**Example:**

Here is your dll code

```
Public Module Library

    <DllExport>
    Public Function Entry(Argument As String)
        MessageBox.Show("Injected With Argument: " + Argument)
        Return 0 'Success
    End Function

End Module
```

Here is example injection code, it is just prototype, TODO: Implement native functions and use them for extension methods used below

```
Public Module Program

    Public Sub Inject(Proc As Process, dll As String)
        Dim K32 = GetModuleHandle("kernel32")
        Dim LLA_Proc = GetProcAddress(K32, "LoadLibraryA")
        'TODO: extension method of process WriteMemory(Byte())
        Dim lns = Proc.WriteMemory(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("C:\FAKE-PATH\Inject.dll"))
        'TODO: extension method of process RemoteCallWait(IntPtr, Arg)
        Dim z = Proc.RemoteCallWait(LLA_Proc, lns)  'Calls method and waits for exit and returns exit code
        'Z should not be zero, otherwise injection is incomplete

        Dim XPTR = GetPtr("C:\FAKE-PATH\Inject.dll", "Entry")
        ''TODO: extension method of process WriteMemory(Byte())
        Dim Loc = Proc.WriteMemory(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("hello world"))
        'TODO: extension method of process RemoteCallWait(IntPtr, Arg)
        z = Proc.RemoteCallWait(XPTR, Loc)
        'Z should be 0 now
    End Sub

    Private Function GetPtr(LibraryName As String, FuncName As String) As IntPtr
        Return CULng(GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(LibraryName), FuncName))
    End Function

End Module
```